# deep cloning related question

Tags: c#

I have implemented an evolutionary algorithm in C# which kind of works but I have the assumption that the cloning does not. The algorithm maintains a population of object trees. Each object (tree) can be the result of cloning (e.g. after ‘natural selection’)  and should be a unique object consisting of unique objects. Is there a simple way to determine whether the ‘object population’ contains unique/distinct objects – in other words whether objects are shared by more than one tree? I hope my question makes sense.

Thanks.

Best wishes,

Christian

PS: I implemented (I think) deep copy cloning via serialization see:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx

Comment: So, you are looking for a way to check you theory that your program makes shallow copies there it should make a deep copies?

Comment: I think you want the clones to reference each other. At one point, you make a clone of an object and put it in another tree. You can register this fact somewhere central or with the original object. Then, from this information, you should be able to later on detect whether an object is distinct or shared. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Pieter - something like this but this sounds quite complicated. Is there no way to determine the 'pointer' of an object or something (i.e. see whether it is actually the same in terms of memory)

Comment: Added an answer. Use ReferenceEquals for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to verify whether two objects are the same objects in memory is by comparing them using Object.ReferenceEquals. This checks whether the "Pointers" are the same.

Comment: Thanks I think that's it. I will check this and I think you answered this before Rob Fonseca-Ensor.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning in C# is by default a shallow copy. The keyword you probably need to google for tutorials is "deep cloning", in order to create object graphs that don't share references.

Comment: see PS - I implemented 'deep cloning' - but i would like to test this. Maybe I can give each object a GUID when it is created/cloned and then check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What about following: Add a static counter to every class for member references of your 'main tree class'. Increment counter it in every counstructor. Determine how many of a 'subobjects'should be contained in tree object (or all tree-objects) and compare that to the counter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, for first, let me see if I get you correctly:

RESULT is a object tree that has some data.

GENERATION is a collection of a result objects.

You have some 'evolution' method that moves each GENERATION to the next step.

If you want to check if one RESULT is equal to the other, you should implement `IComparable` on it, and for each of its members, do the same.

ADDITION:

Try to get rid of that kind of cloning, and make the clones manually - it WILL be faster.  And speed is crucial to you here, because all heuristic comes down to muscle.

Comment: Yes. You could say that the 'evolution' method is the 'natural selection'. It can create several clones of one RESULT depending on how 'fit' the RESULT is. I do not think that IComparable would work as the same object (in terms of data) is not the same if that makes sense. Same object are allowed but they should not be the same in terms of memory.

Comment: Hm, so your generation is something like OBJ1 5 times; OBJ2 3 times; OBJ3 7 times.  Then, your EVOLUTION will combine all their features weighted by the population volume, right.  Then, if you use randomness, you will have to count newborns and categorize them.  There comes IComparable at the highest level.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking is "how do i check if two object variables refer to the same bit of memory, you can call Object.ReferenceEquals